# Not able to build Azure functions in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-functions

I just installed Azure Work Load on Visual Studio 2017. I am not able to build azure functions on Visual Studio 2017. I am not sure if I am missing anything.. Could anyone please point me to what I might be missing. I am using version 4.7.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

manually running nuget package restore fixed it.